# Flip a single hand rig to use with right hand, for Leap Motion / Ultraleap

Tags: rigging

In the first image I have a rig for the left hand in the way that Ultraleap requires, I've tested this and it works in Unreal no problem. **An example of this is in the first image.**

I now need to make a rig for the right hand **that looks like the second image**. Simply **mirroring** or **symmetryizing** along X/Z didn't work for me. Notice how the bones axis has been set to poke out the back of the hand but still along the normal of the mesh, how is this achieved without re-rigging?

It's like the individual bones have been mirrored rather than the rig as a whole, if you see what I mean from the images.

I feel like this should be really easy, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any ideas?

[image: Left Hand][image: Wanted: Right Hand like this]